# How to compare two package version numbers

Tags: php, versions

I'm writing a script in PHP that needs to compare two package version *numbers* to determine which is newer.

PHP has a handy function called `version_compare()`, but it gets really confused with some of the more creative version numbers. For example, `version_compare()` thinks that `0.9.8g-16ubuntu3.1` is newer than `0.9.8o-1ubuntu4.4`.

Anyone know how I can get this to work?

I'm happy to run any command line scripts using `exec()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

take a look to the [dpkg --compare-versions](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/dpkg.1.html) option, it will allow you to ask dpkg to do the comparison :)

```
dpkg --compare-versions 0.9.8g-16ubuntu3.1 lt 0.9.8o-1ubuntu4.4
```

will return 0, that means `0.9.8g-16ubuntu3.1` is lt (lesser than, < ) to `0.9.8o-1ubuntu4.4`

Answer (score 0):

Debian package version numbers have their own, somewhat idiosyncratic set of comparison rules.

So you have broadly three options.

1. Read the spec and implement it yourself.
2. Find an existing implementation for/in your language. There certainly exist options for perl, python and rust, but I can't seem to find one for php.
3. Run dpkg --compare-versions as an external program, easy enough but inefficient if you need to do this in bulk.

Another option might be to use ffi to call a C library that does the comparision, but I'm struggling to find a C library to use. libdpkg has version comparision functions, but they seem to expect the version to be already broken up into epoch, upstream and debian versions.